# Getting notice "Array to string conversion" when using call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to check for matching values in multiple arrays, so I made a multi-dimensional array by pushing them into `$array` and then wrote this line of code:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array);
```

I am getting the result I want, but I am always getting this notice on that particular line of code:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Wondering what's causing this. Hope someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays (the first-level items inside `$array`) themselves contain arrays. This is unsupported by [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), because it treats the array items as strings for purposes of determining equality:

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`.
>   In words: when the string representation is the same.

I can't say definitely without knowing what exactly you are trying to do, but a possible solution is to use [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) instead which will allow you to specify in code how to compare items without necessarily casting them to string.